# OracleCommand Parameter Exception ORA-02017

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I want to execute this sql statement against my db within my c# application:

```
public bool PerformOracleSql(int value)
{
    string SetSessions = @"ALTER SYSTEM SET sessions = :newvalue SCOPE = spfile";
    OracleCommand OraCmd = new OracleCommand(SetSessions, Connection);
    OraCmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("newvalue", value));
    int oraReturn = OraCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (oraReturn == -1) { return false; } else { return true; }
}
```

On execute I get this error: Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: "ORA-02017: integer value required"

The variable "value" has the value of 180. That's of course a valid integer value, isn't it?

I also tried this line

```
OraCmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("newvalue", OracleDbType.Int64, value));
```

or this line

```
OraCmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("newvalue", OracleDbType.Int32, value));
```

Still getting this error. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a bind variable in a DDL, and ALTER SYSTEM/SESSION are DDL statements. You'll need instead to simply use C# string concatenation to assemble the DDL statement with the value.

```
  string SetSessions = @"ALTER SYSTEM SET sessions = " + value + " SCOPE = spfile";
  OracleCommand OraCmd = new OracleCommand(SetSessions, Connection);
  int oraReturn = OraCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```